# Trying to create an htaccess file to handle both extensionless files and missing files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to combine two htaccess rewrite rules: one to handle extensionless links and the other to send missing files to an index page to handle them. I have working code for them separately but combining the two is tricky.

The rules would be such:

1. If the URI is a directory, go to it and let the index file within it handle it.
2. If the URI has an extension and the file exists, go to it.
3. If the URI doesn't have an extension, add .php and go to the file if it exists.
4. For any files that don't exist (with or without extension), send it to the index file to handle it.

The reason for this is that I have some static pages and some created dynamically from the database.

FYI the "extensionless" code is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

and the "redirect to index" code is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [PT,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Both anubhava and Rijul's code works in my tests so thanks to both of you. I accepted anubhava simply because it was first unless someone more knowledgeable can indicate the preferable solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

In case 4, if you have to handle the requests for files that don't exist (with or without extension) you need to know which url is requested inside `index.php`. For that a `GET` `url` param is added which you can use in php file by `$_GET['url']`